# Assign the same string to multiple variables

Tags: bash, assignment

I want to assign the string contained in `$value` to multiple BASH variables.

Actually the example I gave before (`var1=var2=...=$value`) was not reflecting exactly what I wanted.
So far, I found this but it only works if `$value` is an integer:

```
$ let varT=varz=var3=$value
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Shouldn't the question be: Assign the same string value to multiple variables? (subject and object switched)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion you're better of just doing the more readable:

```bsh
var1="$value" var2="$value" var3="$value" var4="$value" var5="$value" var6="$value" var7="$value" var8="$value" var9="$value" var10="$value"
```

But if you want a very short way of accomplishing this then try:

```bsh
declare var{1..10}="$value"
```

*Edited*: using brace expansions instead of printf and declare instead of eval, which could be dangerous depending on what's in `$value`.

Cf. EDIT1: You could still use brace expansions in the new case:

```bsh
declare var{T,z,3}="$value"
```

It's safer than the `printf` approach in the comments because it can handle spaces in `$value`.

Comment: Please see my EDIT1. The `printf` method you gave was just fine if you put the declare in front : `declare $(printf .....)`

Comment: With EDIT1 using `printf` that would be: `declare $(printf "var%s=$value " T z 3)`. But be careful with spaces in `$value`.

Comment: Note that the `declare` approach is still dangerous if any of the variables were previously declared as arrays. Try after `var3=() value='([0$(echo Gotcha>&2)]=)'`

Comment: `eval` is fine if used as `eval var{1..10}=\$value`, that is as long as the (arbitrary) content of `$value` is not evaluated as shell code.

Answer (score 7):

`let` is doing an arithmetic evaluation.  In `bash`, this is equivalent to `(( ... ))`.  This is why your code only works for integers.

Using an array instead of specially named variables:

```
var=( "$value"  "$value" "$value" "$value" "$value" "$value" "$value" "$value" "$value" "$value" )

printf 'var[5]=%s\n' "${var[5]}"
```

or an associative array,

```
declare -A var

var=( ["T"]=$value ["z"]=$value [3]=$value )

printf 'var[T]=%s\n' "${var["T"]}"
```

You could also do a loop:

```
for varname in var0 var1 varT varfoo; do
    declare -n var="$varname"
    var=$value
done
```

This loop loops over names of variables.  In the loop body, a name reference variable is created that references the current loop variable.  When the value of the name reference variable is set, the named variable is set.

Comment: What does the `-n` option do? I get an error with it. Ah... namerefs (>= 4.3, IIRC?)

Comment: @muru Yes, `declare -n` creates a name reference variable. You would have to run `bash` 4.3+ to use name references.

Answer (score 3):

```
value=balabala
eval var{1..10}=\$value
echo $var{1..10}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Value='-%% this is a test %%-'
for VarName in myVar1 myVar2 myOtherVar; do printf -v "$VarName" %s "$Value"; done
```

Answer (score 1):

you could do:

```bsh
declare {varT,varz}="$value"
```